# C# HttpClient custom headers each request

Tags: c#, request, header, httpclient

I've noticed that using HttpClient is **NOT** thread safe when modifying *HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders* but I want to make as many requests as possible.
I need a custom header each request (2 other headers are always the same). Also the URL changes a bit

1. http://example.com/books/1234/readers/837
2. http://example.com/books/854/readers/89
3. http://example.com/books/29432/readers/238
4. ... so on

Currently I'm creating a new HttpClient for every request but I feel like creating 10k+ HttpClients isn't the best choice here.

I'd like to make one static HttpClient with 2 DefaultRequestHeaders and use this HttpClient for every request but also add one custom header.

I want to make this as fast as possible so if you have something else I'll take it.

```
        Parallel.ForEach(Requests, Request =>
        {
            var Client = new HttpClient();
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Header1", "Value1");
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Header2", "Value2");
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Header3", "Value for exact this request");

            var response = Client.PutAsync(new Uri($"http://example.com/books/1234/readers/837"), null); //.Result (?)
            Client.Dispose();
        });
```

Answer (score 11):

Don’t use `DefaultRequestHeaders` for headers that don’t apply to *all* requests the `HttpClient` sends.

Also, don’t create an `HttpClient` per request.

You can do this easily by instead creating one `HttpRequestMessage` for each request, applying whatever headers you need to it, and using the same `HttpClient` throughout to `.SendAsync()` them:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, url)
{
    request.Headers.<add here>;
    // optionally set .Content

    using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request))
    {
        // ... process response
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition, DefaultRequestHeaders is not thread safe, you shouldn't use it if you care about paralellism: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders?view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: The way to use HttpRequestMessage looks great! Do we need the second "using" though?

Answer (score 2):

The standard scenario of using HttpClient since .NET Core 2.1 is:

- create it via
  [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)
- custom headers passed in the body of queries (fixed headers can be
  defined in custom
  [DelegatingHandler](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-aspnetcore-outgoing-request-middleware-pipeline-delegatinghandlers))

Straightforward example with direct passing all headers and without batch-processing:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000)
    .Select(v => HttpClientFactory.Create().SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, new Uri($"http://example.com/books/1234/readers/837"))
    {
        Headers =
        {
            {"Header1", "Value1"},
            {"Header2", "Value2"},
            {"Header3", v.ToString()},
        },
        Content = new StringContent("{test:\"hello\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    }));

var responses = await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
// ..
```

Remarks:

- sending thousands request looks suspicious, are you sure that server
  doesn't have the endpoint for group processing of items
- using
  [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq)
  for the non-CPU consuming tasks isn't correct (quotation: "PLINQ
  queries scale in the degree of concurrency based on the capabilities
  of the host computer")

Answer (score 2):

I think the usage of a `DelegatingHandler` would be able to accomplish what you are looking for. You would stop using DefaultRequestHeaders and instead set them within the `DelegatingHandler`.

Also note, `HttpClient` is threadsafe for requests, and should not be disposed of. This is because it disposes of the underlying `HttpMessageHandler` which causes some lower level inefficiencies. More detail is here http://www.nimaara.com/2016/11/01/beware-of-the-net-httpclient/.

`Sample.cs`

```cs
// .Net Framework, careful here because the sockets will be cached, network changes will break your app
// see http://www.nimaara.com/2016/11/01/beware-of-the-net-httpclient/ for more details

var client = new HttpClient(new MyCustomHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler() });

// .Net Core
client = new HttpClient(new MyCustomHandler() { InnerHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler() { PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) } });

Parallel.ForEach(Requests, Request =>
{

    var response = client.PutAsync(new Uri($"http://example.com/books/1234/readers/837"), null); //.Result (?)

    // do not dispose of httpclient!
});
```

`MyCustomHandler.cs`

```cs
public class MyCustomHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // the static headers
        request.Headers.Add("Header1", "Value1");
        request.Headers.Add("Header2", "Value2");

        // the unique header
        SignRequest(request);

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }


    public void SignRequest(HttpRequestMessage message)
    {
        // usually the pattern of a unique header per request is for an authorization header based on some signature of the request
        // this logic would be here
        // generate the signature
        string signature = new Random().Next(int.MaxValue).ToString();

        message.Headers.Add("Header3", signature);
    }
}
```