# Adding Http-Header to Azure-Durable-Function-Status-Response

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions

I have implemented a durable function started by calling a http-call.

The Http-Endpoint looks like this:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
```

Within the method I start the Orchestrator and at the end of the method I return the StatusResponse by calling `starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId)`

I then call frequently the returned status-url to get the current status and in the end the result of the process.

Now I want to add a custom http-header to the status-url-response that contains some summary about the returned result.

I wasn't able to figure out how it could be possible to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
 public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
```

Here request is defined from the `HttpRequestMessage` class where you have the properties like Headers, Request URI, Content, to define the custom Headers passing to the Request and Custom (User-defined) Response that comes from the Http Request.

You can define the parameters to be passed in the Headers Object for adding the extra content in the Http Requests-Responses.

Refer to this SO [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56297628) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43780538) for the Sample Code Snippets regarding passing the custom Headers and can bind to the Http Request object `req` in the `HttpStart` Function Code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. My question was specific for an azure durable function environment.

When I start the function calling the http endpoint (http://localhost:7071/api/StartPipeline), I get a JSON returning the status-url where I can get the status of my function call. 
"http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/85efb8b5-fcda-41b6-be88-92994b7614e5?taskHub=samplehubname&connection=Storage&code=QixBWGHJ7fJSphlkdUt-nqJytLkkn0DI2HzP6faApzmhAzFuyjC72Q==

when I call this status url I would like to add http headers.